# The servlet mapping ViewRendererServlet refers to a servlet that is not defined web.xml

Tags: java, rad, portal

The servlet mapping `ViewRendererServlet` refers to a servlet that is not defined   web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>NWRedirectPortlet</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have repaired the formatting on your question for you. We really need more information. What is your question? What problem are you trying  to solve? Please explain more in the question what yo are trying to do. Then someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining because you don't have one of these in the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyClass</servlet-class>
    ...
</servlet>
```

**Update**

`<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` are siblings:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I am having <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>

Comment: `<servlet-name>` in `<servlet-mapping>` must match a `<servlet-name>` in a `<servlet>`

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet</servlet-class>
 
 
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ViewRendererServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/servlet/view</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
 </servlet>

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same error. It was not an syntax error, more a problem from eclipse.

Just open the servlet class
(in your case: org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet)
once, and the error magically disapeared.